# Changing/updating amout of items in ng-repeat with limitTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-limitto

Lets say, I am repeating a `div` with using `ng-repeat | limitTo:6` , (and also let say I have 5000 of them)

and when I click on the div , the div will be removed  . And then there will be only 5 items shown.

How can I edit it , so that when an item from the ng-repeat list removed, the next Item will be shown ?

```
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
        <!-- selectingUser(user) ;  -->
        <div ng-if="!user.isSelected" data-ng-click = "selectingUser(user)" data-ng-repeat="user in users " > <!-- | filter:$select.search  -->
            <img class="img-circle" data-ng-src ="{{user.image}}" width="8%"/>
            <span  data-ng-bind-html="user.name" ></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

as you see here, the div will be shown only if `user.isSelected = false`

Comment: What is happening for you after an element is removed from the array?

Comment: When an Element is removed from the array, I have only 4 elements left.(in case i add limitTo:5 ) . adn then 3, and then 2.... 

the next elements will never be added, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div ng-repeat="item in sampleArray | limitTo:5" ng-click="removeItem($index)">{{item}}</div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.sampleArray = ["Obj1", "Obj2", "Obj3", "Obj4", "Obj5", "Obj6", "Obj7", "Obj8", "Obj9", "Obj10"];
            $scope.removeItem = function(index){
                console.log("removing item at" + (index+1));
                $scope.sampleArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Just use the angular `limitTo` property with `ng-repeat`. That will automatically adjust the content when an element is removed

Comment: This is exactly what I search for, when I add the same, It doesnt load the new items tho

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it is from my work, and it has tons of dependencies on it....  `<div data-ng-repeat="user in users | limitTo:5" ng-if="!user.isSelected" data-ng-click = "selectingUser(user)"  > <!-- | filter:$select.search  -->
                <img class="img-circle" data-ng-src ="{{user.image}}" width="8%"/>
                <span  data-ng-bind-html="user.name" ></span>
            </div>`

but this was what I tried.

Comment: What do you mean with using limitTo filter? 

 If you mean , adding   `| limitTo:5 ` in my ng-repeat , then yes I tried it. is there any other way to use that filter?

Comment: No it doesn't  :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove it on click of selectingUser then you can do is

Just set isslected value to true -

```
$scope.selectingUser=function(data){
   angular.forEach($scope.users , function(value, key){
      if(data.id == value.id)
       value.isSelected = true;
    });
}
```

OR Remove it from deep copied array -

```
$scope.selectingUser=function(data){
 angular.forEach($scope.users , function(value, key){
  if(data.id == value.id)
     $scope.users.slice(key);
});
}
```

Comment: I already have that function , I am sorry I think I couldn't explain my problem well. 

I ALWAYS  want my ng repeat to show 6 options, if I delete one, the 7. option should be added

Answer (score 0):

If the functionality is used in many place in project then **directive** can be used to achieve this

For example

let the Controller be

```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [{"id":1,"value":"one"},{"id":2,"value":"two"},{"id":3,"value":"three"},
      {"id":4,"value":"four"},{"id":5,"value":"five"},{"id":6,"value":"six"},
      {"id":7,"value":"seven"},{"id":8,"value":"eight"},{"id":9,"value":"nine"},
      {"id":10,"value":"ten"},{"id":11,"value":"eleven"},{"id":12,"value":"twelve"}]
    });
```

Lets create a directive that limits the ng-repeat variable and removes element on click

```
 app.directive('dirDemo', function ($filter) {
        return {
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            limit:'='
        },
       template: '<div ng-repeat="val in limitedData" ng-click=Remove($index)>{{val.value}}</div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.limitedData=   $filter('limitTo')(scope.data, scope.limit, 0);

                 scope.Remove=function(index){
                   scope.GetLimitedArray(index);
                   scope.TrimArray();
                 }

                 scope.GetLimitedArray=function(index){
                   scope.data.splice(index,1);
                 }

                 scope.TrimArray=function(){
                   if(+scope.limit>0){
                   scope.limitedData= $filter('limitTo')(scope.data, scope.limit, 0);
                 }
                 }
          }
          }
        });
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <dir-demo data="data" limit="5"></dir-demo>
  </body>
```

Working plunker [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1kgqv1xhF7OZe110niYR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Incase your problem was not solved,like mine in this case ,

I tried something different and it worked for me ;

```
$scope.limiting = 6
```

in controller at removing function `$scope.limiting++` and in your 
 adding function `$scope.limiting--`